# Can i give print option to print webform data in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, printing

I have a webform on which i display all the details of a particular record now i want to give my client print functionality so he can print those detail. Can this be done in asp.net and if yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css to specify stylesheets to use for printing.  There's not really anything asp.net specific about it - it's handled by the browser.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood, you want to print part of the page, right?
One option is to use a pop up a new page with content to be printed passed from the current page and let the user print it from the pop up page.

Please refer the following demo:

Print Demo

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function doPrint() 
{
    bdhtml=window.document.body.innerHTML;
    sprnstr="<!--startprint-->";
    eprnstr="<!--endprint-->";
    prnhtml=bdhtml.substr(bdhtml.indexOf(sprnstr)+17);
    prnhtml=prnhtml.substring(0,prnhtml.indexOf(eprnstr));
    window.document.body.innerHTML=prnhtml;
    window.print();
}
</script>

</head>
   <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div id="WithoutPrint">
             This area will not print!
         </div>
         <div id="Print">
            <!--startprint-->
            This area will print!
           <!--endprint-->
        </div>
        <input id="btnPrint" type="button" value="Print" onclick="doPrint()" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps...Thanks.